# Explanation of a regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

What does the following regex mean?

```
fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt"
fname="${fspec##*/}"
```

I know what it does, but not how it does? Fetching fname is not clear to me.

Please explain.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, No but the asker could be forgiven for thinking it is one. For reference shruti, explanation can be found in the bash man page on [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `${var##*/}` syntax strips everything up to the last `/`.

```
$ fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt"
$ echo "${fspec##*/}"
abc.txt
```

In general, `${string##substring}` strips the longest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.

For further reference you can for example check [Bash String Manipulation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/) with several explanations and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the explanation from bash documentation.

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
The  word  is  expanded  to  produce  a pattern just as in pathname
expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of  the  value  of
parameter,  then  the result of the expansion is the expanded value
of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or
the longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted.
```

As per the above explanation, In your example **word=*/** which means zero (or) any number of characters ending with **/**.

```
bash-3.2$fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt"
bash-3.2$echo "${fspec##*/}"   # Here it deletes the longest matching pattern
# (i.e) /exp/home1/
# Output is abc.txt

bash-3.2$echo "${fspec#*/}"    # Here it deletes the shortest matching patter
#(i.e) /
# Output is exp/home1/abc.txt
bash-3.2$
```